# Create a space-efficient Snapshot Set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, iterator, set, snapshot

I received this interview question that I didn't know how to solve.

Design a snapshot set functionality.

Once the snapshot is taken, the iterator of the class should only return values that were present in the function.

The class should provide `add`, `remove`, and `contains` functionality. The iterator always returns elements that were present in the snapshot even though the element might be removed from set after the snapshot.

The snapshot of the set is taken when the iterator function is called.

```
interface SnapshotSet {
  void add(int num);
  void remove(num);
  boolean contains(num);
  Iterator<Integer> iterator(); // the first call to this function should trigger a snapshot of the set
}
```

The interviewer said that the space requirement is that we cannot create a copy (snapshot) of the entire list of keys when calling iterator.

The first step is to handle only one iterator being created and being iterated over at a time. The followup question: how to handle the scenario of multiple iterators?

An example:

```
SnapshotSet set = new SnapshotSet();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
set.add(3);
set.add(4);
Iterator<Integer> itr1 = set.iterator(); // iterator should return 1, 2, 3, 4 (in any order) when next() is called.
set.remove(1);
set.contains(1); // returns false; because 1 was removed.
Iterator<Integer> itr2 = set.iterator(); // iterator should return 2, 3, 4 (in any order) when next() is called.
```

I came up with an O(n) space solution where I created a copy of the entire list of keys when calling iterator. The interviewer said this was not space efficient enough.

I think it is fine to have a solution that focuses on reducing space at the cost of time complexity (but the time complexity should still be as efficient as possible).

Comment: Is there a time requirement on the iterator? Could you not record your structure as a ledger, and your iterator only needs to keep track of the start of the ledger up to the point at which the iterator was created, allowing newer entries to be appended to the ledger while it's iterating? Sure, the iterator would be slow (it would need to check the entire ledger to make sure an element that was `add`ed was not `remove`d), but it would take only O(1) space per iterator.

Comment: @Welbog I think it is fine to have a solution that focuses on reducing space at the cost of time complexity (but the time complexity should still be as efficient as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that makes all operations reasonably fast.  So it is like a set that has all history, all the time.

First we'll need to review the idea of a [skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).  Without the snapshot functionality.

What we do is start with a linked list on the bottom which will always be kept in sorted order.  Draw that in a line.  Half the values are randomly selected to also be part of another linked list that you draw above the first.  Then half of those are selected to be part of another linked list, and so on.  If the bottom layer has size `n`, the whole structure usually requires around `2n` nodes.  (Because `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 2`.)  Each node in the entire 2-dimensional structure has the following data:

```
value: the value of the node
height: the height of the node in the skip list
next: the next node at the current level (is null at the end)
down: the same value node, one level down (is null at height 0)
```

And now your set is represented by a stack of nodes whose values are ignored, that points at the starting node at each level.

Here is a basic picture:

```
  set
   |
start(3)   ->    2
   |             |
start(2)   ->    2      ->      5        ->         9
   |             |              |                   |
start(1)   ->    2   ->    4 -> 5        ->         9
   |             |         |    |                   |
start(0) -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
```

Now suppose I want to find whether `8` is in the set.  What I do is start from the set, find the topmost start, then:

```
while True:
    if node.next is null or 8 < node.next.value:
        if node.down is null:
            return False
        else:
            node = node.down
    elif 8 == node.next.value:
        return True
    else:
        node = node.next
```

In this case we go from `set` to `start(3)` to the top `2`, down one to `2`, forward to `5`, down 2x to `5`, then go `6`, `7`, and find `8`.

That's `contains`.  To `remove` we follow the same search idea, but if we find that `node.next.value == 5` then we assign `node.next = node.next.next`, then continue searching.

To `add` we randomly choose a `height` (which can be `int(-log(random())/log(2))`).  And then we search forward until we've arrived at that height at a node whose `node.next` should be our desired new value.  Then we do something complicated.

```
prev_added = null
while node is not null:
    if node.next is null or new_value < node.next.value:
        if node.height <= desired_height:
            adding_node = Node(new_value, node.height, node.next, null)
            node.next = adding_node
            if prev_added is not null:
                prev_added.down = adding_node
            prev_added = adding_node
        node = node.down
    else:
        node = node.next
```

You can verify that expected performance of all three operations is `O(log(n))`.

So, how do we add snapshotting to this?

First we add a `version` to the `set` data structure.  This will be tied to snapshot.  Next, we replace every single pointer with a linked list of pointers and versions.  And now instead of directly modifying pointers, if the top one has an older version than we're now inserting, you add to the head of the list and leave the older version be.

And NOW we can implement a snapshot as follows.

```
set.version = set.version+1
node = set.start
while node.down is not null:
    node = node.down
snapshot = Snapshot(set, set.version, node)
```

Now snapshotting is very quick.  And to traverse a particular past version of the set (including simply iterating over a snapshot) for any pointer we need to traverse back until we get past any too new pointers, and find an old enough one.  It turns out that any given pointer will tend to have a fairly small number of pointers, so this has only a modest amount of overhead.

Traversal of the current version of the set is just a question of always looking at the most recent version of a pointer.  So it is just an additional layer of indirection, but same expected performance.

And now we have a version of this with all snapshotted versions available forever.  It is possible to add garbage collection to reduce how much of a problem that is.  But this description is long enough already.

Comment: Thank you! Would you add analysis to your answer about the worst-case time complexity for calling iterator.next for the snapshot, especially when a lot of the elements have been deleted?

Comment: The worst case for `iterator.next` is `O(edits)`.  The worst case for iterating all of the way through the snapshot is `O(size + edits)`.  If you switch from linked lists for pointers to a tree structure, you can make the worst case for a single call to `iterator.next` to `O(log(versions))` but the average case and whole iteration gets worse.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very different but ultimately much better answer than the one I gave at first.  The idea is simply to have the data structure be a read-only reasonably well balanced sorted tree.  Since it is read-only, it is easy to iterate over it.

But then how do you make modifications?  Well, you simply create a new copy of the tree from the modification on up to the root.  This will be `O(log(n))` new nodes.  Better yet the `O(log(n))` old nodes that were replaced can be trivially garbage collected if they are not in use.

All operations are `O(log(n))` except iteration which is `O(n)`.  I also included both an explicit iterator using callbacks, and an implicit one using Python's [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

And for fun I coded it up in Python.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__ (self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        count = 1
        if left is not None:
            count += left.count
        if right is not None:
            count += right.count
        self.count = count
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def left_count (self):
        if self.left is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.left.count

    def right_count (self):
        if self.right is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.right.count

    def attach_left (self, child):
        # New node for balanced tree with self.left replaced by child.
        if id(child) == id(self.left):
            return self
        elif child is None:
           return TreeNode(self.value).attach_right(self.right)
        elif child.left_count() < child.right_count() + self.right_count():
            return TreeNode(self.value, child, self.right)
        else:
            new_right = TreeNode(self.value, child.right, self.right)
            return TreeNode(child.value, child.left, new_right)

    def attach_right (self, child):
        # New node for balanced tree with self.right replaced by child.
        if id(child) == id(self.right):
            return self
        elif child is None:
            return TreeNode(self.value).attach_left(self.left)
        elif child.right_count() < child.left_count() + self.left_count():
            return TreeNode(self.value, self.left, child)
        else:
            new_left = TreeNode(self.value, self.left, child.left)
            return TreeNode(child.value, new_left, child.right)

    def merge_right (self, other):
        # New node for balanced tree with all of self, then all of other.
        if other is None:
            return self
        elif self.right is None:
            return self.attach_right(other)
        elif other.left is None:
            return other.attach_left(self)
        else:
            child = self.right.merge_right(other.left)
            if self.left_count() < other.right_count():
                child = self.attach_right(child)
                return other.attach_left(child)
            else:
                child = other.attach_left(child)
                return self.attach_right(child)

    def add (self, value):
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is None:
                child = TreeNode(value)
            else:
                child = self.left.add(value)
            return self.attach_left(child)
        elif self.value < value:
            if self.right is None:
                child = TreeNode(value)
            else:
                child = self.right.add(value)
            return self.attach_right(child)
        else:
            return self

    def remove (self, value):
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is None:
                return self
            else:
                return self.attach_left(self.left.remove(value))
        elif self.value < value:
            if self.right is None:
                return self
            else:
                return self.attach_right(self.right.remove(value))
        else:
            if self.left is None:
                return self.right
            elif self.right is None:
                return self.left
            else:
                return self.left.merge_right(self.right)

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.left is None:
            left_lines = []
        else:
            left_lines = str(self.left).split("\n")
            left_lines.pop()

            left_lines = ["  " + l for l in left_lines]

        if self.right is None:
            right_lines = []
        else:
            right_lines = str(self.right).split("\n")
            right_lines.pop()

            right_lines = ["  " + l for l in right_lines]

        return "\n".join(left_lines + [str(self.value)] + right_lines) + "\n"

    # Pythonic iterator.
    def __iter__ (self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.value
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right



class SnapshottableSet:
    def __init__ (self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def contains (self, value):
        node = self.root
        while node is not None:
            if value < node.value:
                node = node.left
            elif node.value < value:
                node = node.right
            else:
                return True
        return False

    def add (self, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)
        else:
            self.root = self.root.add(value)

    def remove (self, value):
        if self.root is not None:
            self.root = self.root.remove(value)

    # Pythonic built-in approach
    def __iter__ (self):
        if self.root is not None:
            yield from self.root

    # And explicit approach
    def iterator (self):
        nodes = []
        if self.root is not None:
            node = self.root
            while node is not None:
                nodes.append(node)
                node = node.left
        def next_value ():
            if len(nodes):
                node = nodes.pop()
                value = node.value
                node = node.right
                while node is not None:
                    nodes.append(node)
                    node = node.left
                return value
            else:
                raise StopIteration
        return next_value

s = SnapshottableSet()
for i in range(10):
    s.add(i)
it = s.iterator()
for i in range(5):
    s.remove(2*i)

print("Current contents")
for v in s:
    print(v)

print("Original contents")
while True:
    print(it())
```