# Efficient Algorithm for Amount allocation problem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, backtracking, greedy

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to solve the following question.

*We have 2 groups of buckets, which is represented by number arrays. The number is the bucket size. The bucket size and the number of buckets in each group is not limited. But the size sum of 2 group2 are equal. For example:*

```
groupA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
groupB = [3, 3, 2, 2]
```

*If buckets in group A are full of water and buckets in groupB are empty. In each step, we can move certain amount of water from one bucket in groupA to one bucket to groupB. The water amount should not exceed the existing amount in the groupA bucket and the left space in groupB bucket.*

*The question is, find a solution with minimum number of steps to move all water in groupA to groupB.*

I know I can use the brute force search, but it looks to have an exponential time complexity. Greedy is ok, but I cannot prove greedy provides the optimal solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the type of questions that optimal sulotion is only by brute force,
and greedy solution will provide a good enough solution

Answer (score 2):

The [3-partion problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) can be solved with a solver for your problem, so there is no general  efficient algorithm.

It is tricky, but an A* search can efficiently prove that greedy is optimal when it is. The same technique provides solutions if dynamic programming does.

But it does so at the cost of sometimes taking both exponential time and memory.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about using A* to prove optimality? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @KellyBundy It is tricky to get right. But with the right heuristic, you'll try the greedy thing first, and backtrack as little as possible. If greedy simply finds the right answer, you'll find that with a proof that it is optimal.  If greedy needs to do a bunch of suboptimal things, then it takes longer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462145/resource-allocation-algorithm-weights-in-containers/75466248#75466248 for an outline of an A* for a different problem.

Comment: Thanks. Looks this is a NP-complete issue.

Comment: @xin Yes, it is. And reducing 3-partition to it is a proof.