# Fastest way to find a winner in the game of Hex

Tags: python, algorithm, search, time-complexity

I am implementing the game of Hex, where you win if you are able to connect two adjacent sides of the board (top to bottom or left to right, depending on if it is player 1 or 2). For finding neighboring cells I use the hexagonal pattern  (i-1,j), (i,j-1), (i+1,j), (i,j+1), (i-1,j+1), (i+1,j-1).

I have implemented BFS in Python to solve this problem, but I was wondering if there are any better solutions. Would an implementation of DFS or any other algorithm be faster? I also tried to implement Union Find, but that didn't really work out because I am trying to make an AI that checks which of the possible next moves leads to a winning state, and I would have to make a lot of disjoint sets. I considered making a remove method for the Union Find algorithm (so I only have to use one disjoint set), but I am not sure how to implement it or if it would be any faster than BFS.

My code so far:

```
from collections import deque

def check_win(matrix, player):
    queue = deque()
    visited = set()
    if player == 1:
        for r in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if matrix[r][0] == player:
                queue.append((r,0))
                visited.add((r,0))
        while queue:
            r, c = queue.popleft()
            if c == len(matrix) - 1:
                return player
            for x, y in ((r-1,c), (r,c-1), (r+1,c), (r,c+1), (r-1,c+1), (r+1,c-1)):
                if 0 <= x < len(matrix) and 0 <= y < len(matrix[0]) and matrix[x][y] == player and (x,y) not in visited:
                    queue.append((x,y))
                    visited.add((x,y))
        return 0
    else:
        for c in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if matrix[0][c] == player:
                queue.append((0,c))
                visited.add((0,c))
        while queue:
            r, c = queue.popleft()
            if r == len(matrix) - 1:
                return player
            for x, y in ((r-1,c), (r,c-1), (r+1,c), (r,c+1), (r-1,c+1), (r+1,c-1)):
                if 0 <= x < len(matrix) and 0 <= y < len(matrix[0]) and matrix[x][y] == player and (x,y) not in visited:
                    queue.append((x,y))
                    visited.add((x,y))
        return 0
```

Here is an example of a winning state:

```
board = [[0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
         [2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 2, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: How does your BFS/DFS take the possible moves of your opponent into account?

Comment: BFS only checks for a winning state for one player, so after player 1 has made a move BFS checks if there are any paths of 1s, and after player 2 has made a move BFS looks for a path of 2s

Comment: I tried to explain it in the first section of my post. Every cell (i, j) has a neighbor over, under, to the left and to the right of it self, as well as one neighbor at (i+1, j-1) and one at (i-1, j+1). This way every cell that is not at the border or the board has six neighbors in a hexagonal pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline a solution that should be much faster.  But it uses a data structure that I don't see used very much.

As I outlined in [Create a space-efficient Snapshot Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75431526/create-a-space-efficient-snapshot-set/75453554#75453554), we can construct an immutable tree.  And then we can create a point modification of said tree in `O(log(n))` steps with `O(log(n))` extra data.  If you don't keep hold of the root of the old tree, it gets garbage collected.  If you do keep hold of it, you can easily have many versions of the same data set, using very little memory for each version.

There I was just constructing the equivalent of a Python `set`.  But you can also use it to construct the equivalent of a Python `dictionary`.  And once you have that, you can build more complex data structures still.

In particular you can implement a union-find where you can easily try out the effects of playing a new move.

But you can use this in other ways as well.  If you switch your board from an array of arrays to one of these clonable dictionaries AND add a `__hash__` method to the data structure, then you can make moves in time `O(log(n))` (which you exceed anyways doing the union-find) AND you can know when you run into the same board state again.  Which will tend to happen when you're doing your search to 3 or more ply.

But be warned. Using this data structure is algorithmically good.  But a data structure like this implemented in Python runs much slower than stupid native data structures.  So you'll need to benchmark to see whether being clever is worth doing something complicated.  (For small boards, no. For large ones, yes. The cutover requires benchmarking.)

Answer (score 0):

If your boards are suitably small (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)) the most common board sizes are 11x11, 13x13 and 19x19), I'd probably go for a solution using bitmasks and representing rows as n-bit integers (where n is the board size).

For each player you can represent one row of the board as an n-bit integer, so that for a given row, a player has a hex placed at column x if and only if  `row & 2**x` is nonzero.

For example: `11100101` means the player has a hex at index 0, another at index 2, and so on.  The idea is then to use a sweeping line from the first row to the last to keep track of potentially valid paths from one side of the board to the other:

```py
def check_win(board, size):
    sweeping_line = shifted_sweeping_line = pow(2, size) - 1
    for row in board:
        cur = next_sweeping_line = 0
        pointer = 1
        while pointer <= row*2:  # *2 to ensure the last cc is processed
            if row & pointer == 0 and cur:  # found a new cc
                if cur & sweeping_line or cur & shifted_sweeping_line:
                    next_sweeping_line += cur
                cur = 0
            if row & pointer:
                cur += pointer
            pointer *= 2
        sweeping_line, shifted_sweeping_line = next_sweeping_line, next_sweeping_line*2
        if sweeping_line == 0: return False
    return True


# The example winning state
check_win([0b00010, 0b00100, 0b00100, 0b01000, 0b10000], 5)  # True
check_win([0b00010, 0b00100, 0b00100, 0b01000, 0b10000][::-1], 5)  # False
check_win([0b00010, 0b00111, 0b00100, 0b11111, 0b10000], 5)  # True
```

We can update the board like so:

```
def update(board, row, col, value):
    board[row] &= 2**col*value
```

So you can quickly change the board to check if a position is winning for the AI, and then revert it to check a different position, etc.

Some crude benchmarks (using IPython):

```py
b1 = [0b00010, 0b00100, 0b00100, 0b01000, 0b10000]
b2 = [[0, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 1]]

In [7]: %timeit check_win_original(b2, 1)
5.87 µs ± 7.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit check_win(b1, 5)
2.93 µs ± 13.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Where the `check_win_original` is the implementation I've copied from the question (which returns `0` when I call it with the example winning state?).

The bitmask method is about twice as fast, but with the board sizes as small as they are (at least in the example) though this is not particularly compelling given how fast the original function already is - I can rerun these benchmarks with a different board size to what you're using if you'd like.